# Update Dell XPS 13 POST Bitmap Image

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, uefi, dell-xps

I have a Dell XPS 13 9360 running multiple OS's (Win10, Ubuntu and Arch) and would like to change the image displayed when the computer boots up and performs a Power On Self Test.

Currently, it just displays the default Dell logo, and I'd like to be able to change it to an image of my choice.

In my research before posting this question, [I came across multiple possible solutions](https://www.google.com/search?q=dell%20post%20bitmap%20update%20program), however  they're all nearly 20 years old. I'm aware that this can be risky, so I decided not to try them in case they wrecked my perfectly good laptop.

Since all the previous "solutions" I found are from so long ago, this probably might not be possible anymore, but just thought I'd ask, thanks!

Comment: Posts from only 5 years ago in the search query you linked indicate the older utilities still work. So, have you tried it?